# WebService Return Xml result instead of json

Tags: jquery, web-services

that is my code , and i am wonder that why my web service in .net 4.0 always return data as a xml format instead of json .

Webservice :

```
    [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public FileModel HelloWorld()
{      
  FileModel model= new FileModel();
  model.Name = "peyman";

  return model;
}
```

jQuery :

I get files list in drop event with: `var files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;`
and then call `upload(files);`

```js
function upload(files) {

    var data = new FormData();

    jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-' + i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : parameters.Url,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        data : data,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("err");
        }
    });
}
```

Also i tried some thing like :

- `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`
- `Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";`
- Adding `"application/json"` or `"text/json"` to response header

but response content-type is always `"text/xml; charset=utf-8"`